# Asymptotic behaviour of a function whose derivatives vanish asymptotically

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^\infty$ function such that $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}f^{(k)}(t)$ exists for all $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. A neat little trick (apparently due to [Thomas Hill](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2689813?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21101542863763)) shows that $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}f^{(k)}=0$ for $k\geq 1$. Indeed by l'Hopital's rule $$\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}f(t) = \lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\frac{e^t f(t)}{e^t} = \lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\frac{e^t(f(t)+f'(t))}{e^t}=\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}(f(t)+f'(t)),$$
so the claim follows inductively.

Is it possible to draw conclusions about the asymptotic decay of $f'$? For example, is there a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}f'(t)\cdot e^{\delta |t|}=0$? Are there examples when this is not the case?

Comment: What about $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: @Ju'x that looks like an answer to me. Should be fairly easy to prove by induction that $f^{(n)}(x)$ has the form $p(x)/q(x)$ where $q(x)$ has degree $2n+2$ and $p(x)$ has degree $n-1$.

Comment: Yeah, it answers this part of the question. Still is there anything that can be said about the asymptotic decay of f'?

Comment: @jds, What else do you want to know? The limit your curious about goes to infinity in Ju'x's example.

Comment: @Jacob Schlather, A nice answer would be that there always exists a $C^\infty$ function $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} \phi(t)=\infty$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f'(t)\phi(t)=0$. I'm rather new on this website, should I edit/amend the question?

Comment: @jds: logarithm seems to have this property. If it wouldn't then $f'$ would need to decay slower than $1/\log(t)$ and so $f$ would grow faster than $t/\log(t)$ which contradicts the fact that the limit exists. I have really no idea what you want to know about asymptotics since every function decaying to zero at infinity (no matter how slowly) satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @jds Yes, just add another section to your answer, maybe with the precursor "edit:" or "added".